# Can a user edit Vue.js Instance Properties from browsers

Tags: vue.js

I am learning Vue.js and was trying to use prototypes to set global variables(Vue.prototype.$appName = 'My App'). Can a user edit this global variables from browser and will the change get reflected in the application?

Comment: if you are running vue by `npm run prod`, then it's not, but the other ways: CDN(no matter dev or prod), `npm run dev`, it's yes

Comment: So if using `npm run prod`, can prototypes be used to store user information that should not get tampered from UI?

Comment: In principle, the stored info will not be tampered by UI no matter what mode/way vue is running on. what I means is the hacker may hard to edit the variables in browser console if you are running vue by `npm run prod`. If you really care about tampering, use `Symbol` type for your info.